# Python error trying to get data from youtube api

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an issue, i am trying to make Python search for videos through the Youtube API, a part of the code doesn't work. When i try to get the tags of the video, it gives me an error.

So far i have used the example from Google "search_by_keyword".
It has worked well. I have however changed it a little.
What i want is Python to give me video IDs with the tags in that video.
I tried debugging, by making it print the whole "snippet" part of the table, it appears that "tags" are not found at all in "snippet"

only a bit of the code have been added, the rest is working find.

```
for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
 if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
   videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["tags"],
                              search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
print ("Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n")
```

At

```
videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["tags"]
```

i expect it here to give me the tags of the video, but it only comes up with a traceback error "keyerror: tags".

Trying to make it print the whole "snippet" part, gives me everything but "tags" AND "categoryid"

I think the question comes down to:
Where do i find the "tags" element in the data table?

Comment: Can you share what error you have encountered when you are trying to run your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Google's docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) the JSON object *snippet* obtained from Search endpoint has no *tags* member. Therefore, your code getting a KeyError exception exhibits correct behavior.

For reaching the *tags* property of a video resource (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.tags[]) you have to make a separate API call for each video you're interested in on Videos endpoint (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

Addendum: you may alleviate calling the API several times on Videos endpoint for the videos you're interested in by specifying those videos -- in one API call only -- to the parameter *id* as a comma-separated list of *video id*s (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id).